# Java Daemon Threading with JNI

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, jvm, daemon

I have a Java applet that creates a new non-daemon thread like so:

```
  Thread childThread = new Thread(new MyRunnable(_this));
  childThread.setDaemon(false);
  childThread.start();
```

Then my `MyRunnable` object calls a native method that is implemented in C++:

```
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (!ran) {             
            System.out.println("isDaemon: " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
            _applet.invokePrintManager(_applet.fFormType,
                    _applet.fFormName, _applet.fPrintImmediately,
                    _applet.fDataSet);
            ran = true;
        }           
     }
  }
```

This C++ method calls into a C# DLL that shows a form. My problem is, whenever the user navigates away from the page with a Java applet on it, JVM (and my C# form) is killed. I need the form and JVM to remain open until it is closed by the user. I tried setting my thread to be a non-daemon thread, which is working because `System.out.println("isDaemon: " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()` prints `isDaemon: false`.

Is there something related to the way that the C# form is created (is there another thread I'm not accounting for) or something I am overlooking?? My thread is not a daemon thread, but the JVM is being killed anyways.

Comment: The browser is doing this.  You need to open a new frame to hold the C# form so you it will run as long as this window is open.  Is there any reason not use a Javascript/web page for this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey, So a new iFrame containing my applet may solve the problem... The only issue I see here is if a user opens multiple applets at a time, I have multiple applets open accessing the same C++ dll, and I know that won't work because I have had issues in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM started for the Applet is terminated once all pages running applets are closed. This is to avoid malicious or broken pages from hogging resources on your computer. To avoid this, you have several alternatives. You could have a persistent part of your applet running in a frame where users won't navigate away. Or you could emit a warning when they try to navigate away (just like Stack Overflow does when you have part of a question typed in). Or you could use some other, server-side persistence. Or you could try to use webstart instead of an applet.